# Insertar datos mediante un form en la bd no me funciona

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos, mysqli, insert

Estoy intentando insertar registros nuevos en la BD (en este caso libros) mediante un formulario muy sencillo con distintos `input`.

Esa información la tengo que recoger y de ahí insertarla en mi base de datos. Además, en la tabla en la que se visualizan todos mis registros de la base de datos también mostrar los que voy insertando.

```
  if (!empty($_REQUEST['enviar'])){
    $conexion = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'bdlibros');
    if ($conexion->connect_errno) {
        die('Lo siento, pero hubo un problema con la base de datos de libros');
    } else {
        $id = $_REQUEST['id'];
        $titulo = $_REQUEST['titulo'];
        $autor = $_REQUEST['autor'];
        $paginas = $_REQUEST['paginas'];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO libros (id, titulo, autor, paginas) VALUES ('$id','$titulo', '$autor', '$paginas')";
    $statement = $conexion->query($sql);
    header("Location:ejerU5-2pagina.php");
    exit;
    }
}
function visualizar_inputs(){

    $id = isset($_REQUEST['id']) ? $_REQUEST['id'] : '';
    $titulo = isset($_REQUEST['titulo']) ? $_REQUEST['titulo'] : '';
    $autor = isset($_REQUEST['autor']) ? $_REQUEST['autor'] : '';
    $paginas = isset($_REQUEST['paginas']) ? $_REQUEST['paginas'] : '';

    $inputs = "<div><label for=''>Id: <input type='text' name='id' value='$id'>
</label></div>
    <div><label for=''>Titulo: <input type='text' id='titulo' name='titulo' value='$titulo'></label></div>
    <div><label for=''>Autor: <input type='text' id='autor' name='autor' value='$autor'></label></div>
    <div><label for=''>Paginas: <input type='text' id ='paginas' name='paginas' value='$paginas'></label></div>
    <a href='ejerU5-2pagina.php?enviar=1'> Añadir</a>";
    echo $inputs;
}
 function visualizar_tabla(){
    $conexion = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'bdlibros');
    if ($conexion->connect_errno) {
        die('Lo siento, pero hubo un problema con la base de datos de libros');
    } else {

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM libros";
    $result = $conexion->query($sql);
    $resultado = $result ->fetch_object();
    $table = "<table border='1px solid black'>
    
    <td> id</td>
    <td> titulo</td>
    <td> autor</td> 
    <td> paginas</td>
    ";
    if ( $_SESSION['administracion'] == 1){
        $table.="<td> Eliminar</td>";
    }

    while ($resultado != null) {
        $table.=
        "
        <tr>
        <td>".$resultado -> id.
        "</td>
        <td>".$resultado -> titulo."
        </td>
        <td>".$resultado -> autor."
        </td>
        <td>".$resultado -> paginas."
        </td>
        ";
        if ( $_SESSION['administracion'] == 1){
            $table.="<td> <a href='ejerU5-2pagina.php?borrar=".$resultado->id."'> Eliminar</a> </td>";
        }
        $table.= "</tr>";
        $resultado = $result -> fetch_object();
    }

    $table.="</table>";
    echo $table;
    }
}
```

Me saltan varios Warnings cuando inserto datos en los `input` y pulso al botón de Añadir:

> Undefined array key "id" (lo mismo me sucede en el campo titulo, autor y paginas)

> Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Duplicate entry '0' for key 'libros.PRIMARY'

> mysqli_sql_exception: Duplicate entry '0' for key 'libros.PRIMARY'

Comment: Hazle debug a tu página usando `print_r($_REQUEST);`. Revisa por qué el ID está vacío al intentar insertar (seguro tu tabla tiene algún valor por DEFAULT que es cero, pero no nos muestras eso). Revisa por qué el campo `id` no tiene atributo `id` y sólo tiene `name`, a diferencia de los demás...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Los campos de tipo **id** en una tabla deben ser configurados como clave primaria `PK`, deben iniciar en 1 y deben ser auto incrementales *para ser considerados identificadores únicos*.

De esta manera se evitan errores al tratar de calcular el siguiente consecutivo por cuenta propia y al insertar no es necesario enviar valores a este campo ya que el motor de base de datos se encarga de incrementarlo de forma automática.

Después de configurar lo anterior, puedes consultar el último **id** de la tabla:

`SELECT MAX(id) FROM libros` *ejemplo **35***

y ese número lo pasas al final de la siguiente sentencia:

`ALTER TABLE libros AUTO_INCREMENT = numeroObtenido;` *reemplaza **numeroObtenido** por **35***

Prueba setear las variables usando el método que uses, `$_POST` o `$_GET` directamente en lugar de usar `$_REQUEST` ya que esta última es una variable superglobal que encapsula el contenido de `$_POST`, `$_GET` y `$_COOKIE`. [Aquí la documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php)

`$titulo = $_POST['titulo'];`

Ahora, la sentencia para insertar un nuevo libro te quedaría así:

`$sql = "INSERT INTO libros (titulo, autor, paginas) VALUES ('$titulo', '$autor', '$paginas')";`

Si aún así, no funciona, deja un comentario o edita tu pregunta y agrega más información que pueda ser útil para analizar el caso de una manera mas exacta.

Answer (score 1):

**Saludos.**

Revisa la tabla `libros` donde realizas el `INSERT`; verifica para tu caso que el campo `id` este como autoincrement (o su respectiva forma).
En tu sentencia `INSERT` no lo incluyas como parte de los valores, y que la BD por sí misma se encargue de generarlo en cada `INSERT`.

Lo anterior implica que tu SQL:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO libros (id, titulo, autor, paginas) VALUES ('$id','$titulo', '$autor', '$paginas')";
```

sea/quede:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO libros (titulo, autor, paginas) VALUES ('$titulo', '$autor', '$paginas')";
```

Desde luego cuando agregues en su momento la parte de `UPDATE` ahí sí necesitas obtener el `ID` al cual corresponden los datos que recibes; ya que por el momento solo haces/tienes `INSERT`.

Answer (score 0):

Lo solucioné modificando la función visualizar_inputs, no recogía los datos al no meter los inputs dentro de un form junto con el método post:
  `function visualizar_inputs(){ $inputs = "<form action='ejerU5-2pagina.php?enviar=1' method='post'>         <div><label for='id'>Id: <input type='text' id='id' name='id' '> </label></div> <div><label for='titulo'>Titulo: <input type='text' id='titulo' name='titulo' ></label></div> <div><label for='autor'>Autor: <input type='text' id='autor' name='autor'></label></div> <div><label for='paginas'>Paginas: <input type='text' id ='paginas' name='paginas'></label></div> <input type='submit'/> </form>"; echo $inputs; }`